# Potential difference in parallel plate capacitors

Tags: electric-fields, potential, potential-energy, voltage, capacitance

I calculated the potential gain/difference for these two cases.

[image]

And found that, voltage difference would be higher for the parallel plate capacitor (2nd one). So from my understanding, the capacitor in 2nd case would have less capacitance than the first one which I clearly know is wrong according to my study material given here,

[image]

Here,the potential difference decreases compared to the first case thereby increasing the capacitance of the capacitor. And I know intuitively the voltage has to decrease when an oppositely charged conductor comes near the other one, But I think that's only when we consider the net potential at plate 1 alone. Also the potential difference given here is $V_1$-$V_-$ where $V_1$ is potential of the plate 1 and $V_-$ potential due to plate 2 at plate 1. But isn't $V_1$-$V_-$ the net potential at plate 1 alone? And shouldn't the actual potential difference value be the one I have calculated down here?

[image]

Why they just took this value '$V_1$-$V_-$' for the potential difference which clearly is net potential at plate 1 and not the potential difference since the potential difference would be the difference between net potential at plate 1 and plate 2. Because if we take the net potential at plate 1 alone, the capacitance seems like increasing which is how its given in my material too, but if we take the potential difference I calculated above, the capacitance decreases. Why this contrast in my understanding?

Comment: What are you moving in the first case, with jyst one plate?

Comment: @nasu a positive unit charge. By that I mean the work done in moving a positive unit charge in that distance d.